# Very slow Numpy buffer pointer access

Tags: python, performance, numpy, cython

I'm trying to get the pointer to a Numpy array so that I can manipulate it quickly in my Cython code. I found two ways of getting the buffer's pointer, one using `array.__array_interface__['data'][0]` and the other with `array.ctypes.data`. They are both painfully slow.

I have created a small Cython class that simply creates a numpy array and stores the pointer to its buffer:

```
cdef class ArrayHolder:
    cdef array
    cdef long *ptr

    def __init__(ArrayHolder self, allocate=True):
        self.array = np.zeros((4, 12,), dtype=np.int)
        cdef long ptr = self.array.__array_interface__['data'][0]
        self.ptr = <long *>ptr
```

Then, back in Python, I create multiple instances of this class, like so:

```
for i in range(1000000):
    holder = ArrayHolder()
```

This takes around 3.6 seconds. Using `array.ctypes.data` is half a second *slower* .

When I comment out the call to `__array_instance__['data']` and run the code again, it completes in around 1 second.

Why is obtaining the address of the Numpy array buffer so slow?

Comment: Of course, taking an entire second to allocate a 400 byte array 500,000 times is also quite wasteful, but it's a known fact Numpy shines with larger arrays.

Comment: Try creating the array with `np.ones`.  `np.zeros` (and `empty`) may be delaying a full allocation.  We want to fully separate array creation from fetching this pointer.

Comment: I don't have the motivation to actually time this myself right now, but I think if you statically type the array (so Cython knows what it is at compile time): `cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=2] array` (with `cimport numpy as np` at the top of the file) and get the pointer using `cdef long ptr = &self.array[0]` it'll probably be a lot faster.

Comment: @hpaulj, I noticed this behavior in a real application where the arrays are either filled with non-trivial values or copied with np.copy from arrays filled with non-trivial values.

Comment: @DavidW - this indeed did the trick! You should write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be helped a lot by using Cython's static typing mechanisms. That way Cython is aware that what you're dealing with is an appropriate type of array array, and can generate optimised C code.

```
cimport numpy as np # just so it knows np.int_t

cdef class ArrayHolder:
    cdef np.int_t[:,:] array # now specified as a specific array type
    cdef np.int_t *ptr # note I've changed this to match the array type

    def __init__(ArrayHolder self, allocate=True):
        self.array = np.zeros((4, 12,), dtype=np.int)
        self.ptr = &self.array[0,0] # location of the first element
```

In this version there's a small cost at the assignment of `self.array` to check that the object is in fact an array. However, element lookup and taking the address are now around as fast as using a C pointer.

In your old version it was an arbitrary python object, so there was a dictionary lookup for `__array_instance__`, a dictionary lookup for `__getitem__` to allow a dictionary lookup for `data`. A further dictionary lookup for `__getitem__` to allow to you find index 0.

One thing to note: if you've used `cdef` to tell Cython the array type, you can do all your indexing directly on the array and it'll be pretty much type same speed as using the pointer, so you can probably skip creating the pointer entirely (unless you need it to pass to external C code). [Turn off `boundscheck` and `wraparound`](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/compilation.html#compiler-directives) for the last little bit of speed.

Comment: Cython complains when declaring attributes as ndarrays, claiming only local variables can be of that type.

Comment: @zmbq Sorry! Should have tested it first (and not just trust my memory)! I've switched it to using the newer style ["typed memoryviews"](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) instead which do work as class attributes. The performance is essentially the same, and they work with a wider range of array types (i.e. not just numpy arrays), so it's a better option anyway.

Comment: My experience with typed memory views is that they are very slow to set up. Even slower than numpy arrays. I changed all buffers to ordinary C buffers I manage myself and now things are really flying.

Comment: They're about 20% slower to set up I think. But yes - handling the memory yourself in C is clearly the fastest option by a long way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing, it's some sort of lazy-loading. Numpy only does the `memset()` on the table when you first access it. I would try to create this array without filling it with zeros to gain time.

Here's my test:

```
import numpy as np

cdef class ArrayHolder:
    cdef array
    cdef long *ptr

    def __init__(ArrayHolder self, allocate=True):
        self.array = np.zeros((4, 12,), dtype=np.int)

    def ptr(ArrayHolder self):
        cdef long ptr = self.array.__array_interface__['data'][0]


from timeit import timeit
from cyth import ArrayHolder


print(timeit("ArrayHolder()", number=1000000, setup="from cyth import ArrayHolder")) 
print(timeit("ArrayHolder().ptr()", number=1000000, setup="from cyth import ArrayHolder"))



$ python test.py                     
1.0442328620702028
3.4246508290525526
```